# how can i add a html div insid a tr tag to span the whole row

Tags: html

I want to be able to add a div element inside a `<tr>` tag and have it span the entire row in a table. Currently, all i have is just a plain html table with no ideas how to proceed. I've tried to do this:

```
<tr>
    <div class="row">
        <p>stuff here</p>
    </div>
</tr>
```

but somehow the `<p>` tag appears to float above the table. How can i fix it? I have an image illustrating what i want to achieve here:

[image]

Comment: are you using a table to try to force layout? if so, investigate a proper css grid system.

Comment: You must put a `td` inside a `tr` and then put anything in that `td`.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by force layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do a column that spans all the columns

```
<tr><td colspan="number_of_cols"> stuff here</td><tr>
```

Otherwise I would suggest building the entire table using divs